# How do I make flexbox even begin to work? It's doing nothing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I cannot get flexbox to work. I've tried all sorts of CSS properties, but it doesn't want to work. `display-flex` doesn't seem to do anything to the page at all. I tried various tags, like `flex-direction:column`, and `text-align: center`, but nothing works. Why won't flexbox do anything?

Expected result:

[image: expected result]

My current result:
https://replit.com/@elliotsFinal/what-to-study#index.html

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class=flex-container>

<h3>WHAT TO STUDY</h3>
  
  <h1>What are your interests?</h2>
  


<fieldset>
    <legend>Pick one from this list</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="data" name="list-1" value="data"
             checked>
      <label for="data">data</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="math" name="list-1" value="math">
      <label for="math">mathy</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="theory" name="list-1" value="theory">
      <label for="theory">theory</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>And one from this list</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="people" name="list-2" value="people"
             checked>
      <label for="people">people</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="problem solving" name="list-2" value="problem solving">
      <label for="problem solving">problem-solving</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="art" name="list-2" value="art">
      <label for="art">art</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
<P>Please select one choice in each list</P>
  
</footer>

</div>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
display: flex
flex-direction: column
background-color: DodgerBlue

}


.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.list-1 {
  
}


.list-2 {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few errors and omissions in your code that need to be corrected:

**CSS**

- Flexbox goes only one level deep (FBL parent vs. flexed child) => the fieldsets need to be a *flexbox* parent row inside `.flex-container` parent for the `<div>` inside.
- `.flex-container` => two missing semi-colons
- `.flex-container > div` => should be `.flex-container > fieldset > div`
- `.list-1`, `.list-2` => should be `[name="list-1"]` and `[name="list-2"]` as you don't use the classes in your HTML tags.

**HTML**

- missing `</body>`
- orphaned `</div>`
- error `<div class=flex-container>` should be `<div class="flex-container">`
- h1 vs h2 => `<h1>What are your interests?</h2>`
- given the example image => `<h3>` and `<h1>` should come before the `<div class=".flex-container">`, not be a part of it.

**Semantics (a11y = accessibility)**

- `<h3>` and `<h1>` => should be `<div>` with different font settings

**In below snippet** you will find the corrected code with some comments. I did *not* provide anything even resembling 'responsive design' nor did I attempt to create the final design, leaving it up to you to implement.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

h1,h3 { text-align: center }
h3    { letter-spacing: 0.3rem } /* 'stretch' the text */

.flex-container {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;          /* had missing semi-colon */
    flex-direction: column; /* dito */
    background-color: DodgerBlue;

    width : max-content; /* restrict W/H to its content => the fieldset */
    height: max-content;
    
    margin: 5rem auto; /* some top/bottom space, 'auto' centers horizontally */
}

.flex-container > fieldset {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-container > fieldset > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

[name="list-1"] { /* rule for radio group named 'list-1' */ }
[name="list-2"] { /* rule for radio group named 'list-2' */ }
```

```html
<h3>WHAT TO STUDY</h3>
<h1>What are your interests?</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pick one from this list</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="data" name="list-1" value="data" checked> <label for="data">data</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="math" name="list-1" value="math"> <label for="math">mathy</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="theory" name="list-1" value="theory"> <label for="theory">theory</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>And one from this list</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="people" name="list-2" value="people" checked> <label for="people">people</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="problem solving" name="list-2" value="problem solving"> <label for="problem solving">problem-solving</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="art" name="list-2" value="art"> <label for="art">art</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
  <p>Please select one choice in each list</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: The point about semantics is certainly backwards; <h1> is a semantic tag, <div> is not. Good accessibility requires using semantic tags - <h1>, <article> and so on - _not_ div's for everything with differing styling. For the best accessibility, a page should also have aria attributes, little to no text inside images and title attributes on links/ images.

Answer (score 1):

There's various issues here.

`<div class=flex-container>` should be `<div class="flex-container">`.

`.flex-container > div` means "target DIVs that are direct children of .flex-container", but your container's direct children are headings and fieldsets.

Not related to your issue, but `<h1>What are your interests?</h2>` is invalid markup - make sure your opening and closing tags match.

Comment: Coincidentally that h1 mismatch is so common on the web that HTML5 standardised correcting it automatically; i.e. [browsers fix it automatically](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) these days

Comment: @Luke Briggs That's interesting, I wasn't aware of that. I'd still rather write valid code in case it's not a browser that's consuming the markup (e.g. a parser or some other mechanism), rather than relying on the fact the code will be fixed.

Comment: yep certainly always best to fix it when it's noticed (well spotted by the way!); there's plenty of regex parsers out there which handle HTML incorrectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps: https://replit.com/@MatijaJanji/what-to-study#style.css

Besides the issues by geat, you're targeting the wrong element with the flex property. In the example above, I'm targeting all the divs that have fieldset as the parent. I'm not sure if that's what you were after.